# I'm looking for a word to describe artificially inflating a price to keep it consistent

Tags: word-choice, finance

As the title says - I'm struggling to find a word to describe the value that is added to the price charged for something to avoid passing on manufacturing savings to the customer.

For example if building a ship costs my company $1000 and we charge $2000 to the customer.

We then change suppliers and the ship now costs $800 to build.

However we want to still charge $2000 for the ship, so is there a name for that $200 we add to into the price to keep it the same?

Note that it doesn't have to be an actual technical financial term - just an English word that  has this kind of inflation meaning

Comment: We could say that we 'are not passing on the cost saving to the customer'.

Comment: Sounds like *markup.*

Comment: Thanks @Autoresponder, yes _markup_ does work but in this case the price already has a markup which is distinct from this extra value

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Subsidizing usually goes the other way... from my understanding... the government subsidizes something to keep the price **low** not to keep it high.

Comment: @Catija Yes of course, you're right, sorry (deleted)

Comment: This is called an increase in *gross margin*  the *asp* (average selling price* is not changed. You’ve gone from 50% GM to 60% GM.

Comment: @Jim So, 'an increase in gross margin brought about by bringing down costs of materials rather than increasing final price'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth right. Typically you can’t just raise your price to achieve the GM you want and remain competitive.

Comment: Jim's 'answer' is certainly relevant (but notice that an increase to $2200 say would bring about the same increase in 'gross margin', so the term is not specific to the non-passing-on of savings to the customer. @WS2 has the idiomatic answer; I'm not sure that there's a shorter or more business-speak alternative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - while that’s certainly true, in practice no one ever announces an improvement in GM by hiking the price.  When an improvement to gross margin is announced it’s always due to reducing costs via process improvements, test time reduction, yield improvements etc.

Comment: @Jim But we're discussing terminology here on ELU, not best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "markup" has been [suggested in comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139391/im-looking-for-a-word-to-describe-artificially-inflating-a-price-to-keep-it-con#comment286077_139391), with the [response](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139391/im-looking-for-a-word-to-describe-artificially-inflating-a-price-to-keep-it-con#comment286083_139391) that "markup does work but in this case the price already has a markup which is distinct from this extra value".

This [site about accounting](http://www.accountingcoach.com/terms/M/markup) suggests that while markup can simply mean "the difference between cost and the selling price" (ie. the difference between $1000 and $2000 in your example), there is a further meaning in retail of "the 'additional' markup from the original selling price [because of things like stock shortages and high demand]" (ie. the $200 you add to the price because of your supplier change).

So I'd suggested using the phrase "additional markup".

Comment: I believe this is an incorrect interpretation of the term. The accounting  article implies that an increase in price is involved:  'For example, an item with a cost of $10 might normally be priced at $15. However, because of the shortage of this item and because of high demand, the retailer sets a selling price of $17. Sometimes markup means the $7, but sometimes it means the additional markup of $2.' Both are add-ons, 'markups', not cuts in production costs.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for may well be Price Gouging.

Comment: You should include a full definition for the term (with a source reference).